# Minecraft- Enabling Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I own quite a cool minecraft server but the command blocks are not enabled. I turned it to "true" in the server settings but it's still not working. This is extremely important because it makes sure that the players will not cheat in KitPvP, Survival, etc. Please answer.

Comment: Was the server restarted after you changed the setting?

Comment: "it makes sure that the players will not cheat in KitPvP, Survival, etc." It is riskier with Command Blocks enabled, you know that, right?

Comment: @ardaozkal Players won't be able to use command blocks without operator and creative, so it shouldn't be riskier. I'm imagining OP wants a command block system to keep players from getting out the KitPvP arena or similar.

Comment: @colorfusion it is terribly dangerous if an op/creative account gets compromised.

Comment: @ardaozkal You can't write or move command blocks with just creative, so it'd probably need to be an operator account. If an operator account is compromised, and the hacker somehow happens to know the server (which is already going to be a very rare occurrence not reasonably worth worrying about), then they can already do enough damage to ruin the world; command blocks aren't really going to change much.

Answer (score 2):

Restart or Reload the server, and it should work. If it doesn't, look at the config file and see if you had a typo anywhere.

Another, more easy and reliable way to prevent cheaters is to install CombatLog and/or NoCheat+.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too with my minecraft server and what you have to do is make sure in the server.properties "enable command blocks" is set to true and then reset your server (turn it off and then on again).